# "Conjugate" of a monotone unbounded function $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, functions

Fix $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. I remember reading (a few years back) about a way to define a "dual" or "conjugate" of an unbounded monotone function $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. But I do not remember the source, nor can I reproduce any nice properties or theorems satisfactorily. The definition I am thinking of goes like this. For an unbounded monotone $f$, define $f^\star$ by:

> $$
> f^\star (y) = \min \{ x \in \mathbb N \,:\, f(x) \geq y \} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{(proposed)}
> $$

It's easy to show that $f^\star$ is also unbounded monotone. I think this definition is more or less correct, but I might very well be wrong on the precise details.

My questions are:

1. Has this or a similar object been studied before systematically? What is the standard terminology for it?
2. <strike>I remember that the $\star$ operation is involutive: $(f^\star)^\star = f$, and I am looking for a proof or a counter-example. (Note that this property will also make this operation automatically bijective.) I have a weak argument showing it's true, but it's not  at all convincing.</strike> \\ *EDIT: For the above definition, $(f^\star)^\star \neq f$ in general. But it turns out the definition can be tweaked if we want this property to hold. See Arturo's answer for details.*

Finally, if this operation makes sense, I feel it should actually be a special case of a more general construction for functions defined on, for instance, lattices. As a bonus question, are any such generalizations known and is there any reference that discusses them? *EDIT: Qiaochu's answer gives such a generalization.*

Comment: Say $f(n) = 10^n$; then your definition is $f^*(m) = \lceil \log_{10}(m)\rceil$. The first few values of $f^*$ are $1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,\ldots$; so $f^*(2)=1$. But $(f^*)^*(1) = \min\{x\mid f^*(x)\geq 1\} = 1$. So $(f^*)^*\neq f$.

Comment: @Arturo I was staring at your counterexample for quite some time, and I found the fix that will give us $(f^\ast)^\ast=f$. Make the inequality sign in $f^\ast$ definition strict, and things work. I have  (what looks like) a proof, I am writing it up informally to see if there's any bug. Now I would like some advice. I want to edit the question, but I also do not want to invalidate the answers below. What's the best thing I can do at this stage? I still would like to have references, so Question (1.) is still relevant, though Question (2.) may not be relevant. Sorry if I am bothering you.

Comment: Srivatsan: First, the justification I wrote above does not actually make sense, though the example still works. What it should be is that $(f^*)^*(2) = \min\{m\mid f^*(m)\geq 2\}=11\neq f(2)$.

Comment: Second: to avoid invalidating the answers, why not post an addendum, indicating this is done after the other answers were posted?

Comment: By the way, I think that with the definition as you have in the post you get that $(f^*)^*(m) = f(m-1)+1$ for $m\geq 1$, by using an argument similar to the one I used to show the new definition works.

Comment: @Arturo Oh, interesting.  Nice observation. In retrospect, that makes sense because $y > f(x)$ is the same as saying $y-1 \geq f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a special case of an [adjoint functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors). (Recall that posets are categories in which $a \le b$ means there is a single arrow $a \to b$, and that functors between such posets are order-preserving functions.) This is discussed in my blog post on the [adjoint functor theorem for posets](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/the-adjoint-functor-theorem-for-posets/).

For the special case of posets, adjoint functors are also known as [Galois connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection), the motivating example being the Galois connection between subextensions of a finite Galois extension and subgroups of a Galois group.

Answer (score 3):

With the original definition of $f^*$, the function $f(n)=10^n$ is a counterexample. Note that 
$$(f^*)^*(2) = \min\{k\in\mathbb{N}\mid f^*(k)\geq 2\} = 11,$$
since $f^*(1)=\cdots=f^*(10)=1$, but $f^*(11)=2$ (since $2$ is the smallest number such that $f(k)\geq 11$). But $f(2)=100\neq 11=(f^*)^*(2)$.

---

As suggested by Srivatsan in the comments, let us tweak the definition of $f^*$ to:
$$f^*(n) = \min\{m\in\mathbb{N}\mid f(m)\gt n\}.$$

I claim that under this definition, $(f^*)^*=f$.

**Lemma.** $f^*(s)\gt t$ if and only if $f(t)\leq s$.

*Proof.* Suppose $f^*(s)\gt t$. Then $\min\{ m\in \mathbb{N}\mid f(m)\gt s\}\gt t$. Therefore, $t\notin\{m\in\mathbb{N}\mid f(m)\gt s\}$, so $f(t)\leq s$.

Conversely, assume that $f(t)\leq s$. Because $f$ is monotone increasing, if $k\leq t$, then $f(k)\leq s$. Therefore, $f^*(s)=\min\{m\in\mathbb{N}\mid f(m)\gt s\}\gt t$. $\Box$

**Proposition.** With the modified definition, $(f^*)^* = f$.

*Proof.* Let $t\in\mathbb{N}$. We have:
$$\begin{align*}
(f^*)^*(t) &= \min\bigl\{ s\in\mathbb{N}\mid f^*(s)\gt t\bigr\}\\
&= \min\bigl\{ s\in\mathbb{N}\mid f(t)\leq s\}\\
&= f(t).\quad\Box
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

It looks morally like a kind of inverse to me.

Start with any binary relation $R\subseteq \mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ that preserves order in the sense that $$x R y \land x' R y' \Rightarrow (x<x' \Leftrightarrow y<y')$$
and such that $R$ is an infinite set.

Then we can derive $f$ from $R$ setting
$$f(x) = \min \{ y \mid x' R y \land x' \ge x \}$$

$f^*$ is then the function that would be derived in the same way from the inverse of $R$. Duality would follow by showing under appropriate conditions we can recover $R$ from $f$.

Comment: Duality shouldn't be expected, since in general there are arbitrarily long chains of adjoint functors: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9849/iterated-adjoint-functors .

Comment: Then what I'm constructing is probably not an adjoint. It would still look sufficiently close to Srivatsan's vague description that it could be what he remembers, I think.

Comment: @Qiaochu -- also note that I'm working specifically in $\mathbb N$, here not in a general poset.